# Access to type of DeclarationMirror

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I need to access the type of `DeclarationMirror`. In the [DeclarationMirror public API](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-mirrors/DeclarationMirror-class.html) I can't see any method or property to access the type, but in Dartium, the `DeclarationMirror` missing property `type` is working and returning a `ClassMirror` with the type of the `DeclarationMirror`.

```
> declare is DeclarationMirror
< true
> declare.type
< ClassMirror on 'Logger'
> declare.type.reflectedType
< class Logger
```

Is safe using this way to get the type of DeclarationMirror?

If it is not safe, there is any other way safer to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: This was raised [on github](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/31597) as well, and I think the responses given there resolved the issue.